# Reverse two input array in java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I reverse this code? I thought that I'm using the right way to reverse this array, but it still doesn't work...

I hope someone can help me. tq

so, this is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class ArrayYear
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int[] arr = new int[3];
       int[] year = new int[3];

       //read element into array 
       for (  int i=0 ; i <= arr.length ; i++ )
       {
           arr[i] = in.nextInt() ;  // input value 

            for ( int j=0 ; j<=arr.length/2 ; j++ ){

                  int temp = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = arr[arr.length - i - 1 ];
                  arr[arr.length - i - 1 ] = temp;               
          }   

           year[i]= in.nextInt();

           System.out.println( "ID :" + arr[i] + "("+ year[i] +")" ) ;
       }      
    }
}
```

note : the array that needed to be reverse is only the first array `arr[i]`

Comment: you should fill the array completely first then reverse what you are doing is insert first element in array then reverse the array then same for second and so on So place the j loop after i loop.Also i loop should be upto `i <= arr.length-1`

Comment: sorry sir , but i still can't get it :( 
should i make the loop in seperate way ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill the array first then reverse it and also loop should be upto `i<=arr.length-1`.Reversing the array code would be

```
public static int[] reverseArray(int a[]) {

    int b[] = new int[a.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    b[index++] = a[i];

    return b;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    int c[] = new int[5];
    int index = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        c[index++] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().trim());
    }
    System.out.println("Before Reverse " + Arrays.toString(c));
    System.out.println("After Reverse " + Arrays.toString(reverseArray(c)));
}
```

Input

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output

```
Before Reverse [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
After Reverse [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/2OO57H)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        int[] arr = new int[3];
        int[] year = new int[3];

        // read element into array
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // input value
            arr[i] = in .nextInt();
            year[i] = in .nextInt();

            // reverse array   
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length / 2; j++) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[arr.length - j - 1];
                arr[arr.length - j - 1] = temp;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < year.length / 2; j++) {
                int temp = year[j];
                year[j] = year[year.length - j - 1];
                year[year.length - j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // print array
            System.out.println("ID :" + arr[i] + "(" + year[i] + ")");
        }
    }
}
```